80s/90s sci fi children's novel about a future TV star on Earth who is visited by a space woman
So when I was about 9 or 10(this would have been 2014 or 2015) I found a sci fi book in obe of my classrooms. I didn't read it(wasn't much of a reader back than), but I did flip through the pages, and the memory of that book just came back to me, so I want to try and find it. Anyways, I remember said book took place in the future and the protagonist was a tv star who's show started getting broadcast to the planet zoregan(not sure of the spelling, other than it rhymes with oregon). And so a space woman who doesn't realize he's an actor arrives on earth to meet him. I remember from the cover art the space woman looked human, but had three eyes and was covered in white fur. I think she also tries to gift the TV star a rat thing called... a zangaroo I think? Anyways, that's all I can remember. Hope somebody could find it!

This might be Alien Obsession by Bruce Richards.  The blurb on Goodreads says:

Matt Pierce, who plays Matt King, the hero of the first television program to be shown on another planet, invites Xena, his biggest fan from Planet Zagon, to visit, but they both find things aren't quite what they expected.

Matt is gifted a zangaroo by Xena.

"Mr. King, I brought you this gift from Zagon," Xena said. She gestured to the black box on the floor. "It's a Zangaroo."
"A kangaroo?" Matt asked.
"She said a Zangaroo," Professor Green corrected him.

The planet Xena comes from is "Zagon," which is close to the "Zoregon" you remember.

Holy crap that's it! I didn't know my question was going to be answer3d so easily. Thanks a lot!

@Dayton Always pleased to help!  You should accept this answer by clicking on the checkmark under the voting arrows in the upper-left of this answer.  That will inform future searchers that your question has been answered, making your question more useful.
